# Showing an image in a picturebox, which is tied to another column (name) like a Search Bar

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm wanting to show a specific image in a picturebox, when a name is selected in a combobox, like a search bar, example:

Hitting or typing Router x

*Picture of this router appears on the picture box*

I'm using a SQL Server to save the data of the router's name and its image, but when I select the router, it's only showing the last image registered in the database

At that code:

```
    private void pesquisar_roteador_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(strcon);
        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand();
        string query = "SELECT NOME FROM roteadores";
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, cn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "roteadores");

        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "NOME";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "ID";
        comboBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables["roteadores"];
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(strcon);
            cn.Open();
            string query = "SELECT FOTO FROM roteadores";
            SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(query,cn);               
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adp.Fill(ds, "roteadores");
            int c = ds.Tables["roteadores"].Rows.Count;

            if (c > 0)
            {
                Byte[] byt = new Byte[0];
                byt = (Byte[])(ds.Tables["roteadores"].Rows[c - 1]["FOTO"]);
                MemoryStream stm = new MemoryStream(byt);
                pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(stm);
            }
            cn.Close();
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're not doing anything to filter the records. For that, you'll need the [WHERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/where-transact-sql) keyword.

Comment: How do i catch a value from a combobox whit WHERE? P.S: NOME = NAME; FOTO = IMAGE;

string query = "SELECT FOTO FROM roteadores WHERE NOME = %comboBox1.Value%; ???

Comment: I would start by just using a hardcoded dictionary, and move to using SQL when that works. When using databases you should use [parameterized queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/data-access/accessing-the-database-directly-from-an-aspnet-page/using-parameterized-queries-with-the-sqldatasource-cs) to avoid sql injection when taking parameters from the user.

Comment: It always returns the last record's image because of `Rows[c - 1]`. But this is very inefficient, returning every image in the table. Your first query should probably be `SELECT ID, NOME FROM roteadores` so that you can pass the selected `ID` value through to the second query to return only the row of interest.